# Как из Flask передать данные в JS?

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

Предположим есть список вида:

```
lst_data_flask = [{'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}, {'key1':'val3', 'key2':'val4'}]
```

Как передать в функцию **print_consoleJS()** JS?

```
<input type="submit" onclick="print_consoleJS()" value="ok">
```

Строка передается без проблем:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="print_consoleJS('{{ string_data_flask }}')" value="ok">
```

**Собственно сам вопрос:** как передать в JS-функцию список словарей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-общем, разобрался. Если кто столкнется с такой же проблемой:

Внутри Flask преобразуем в json-строку и передаем::

```
....
return render_template("URL.html", jsonStr = json.dumps(lst_data_flask,  sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

В шаблонизаторе передаем:

```
<ul class ="pagination"  id="id_pagination" onclick="createPagenation({{ jsonStr }})">
```

И внутри JS может работать уже по ключам и индексам:

```
console.log(jsonStr[0]['key1'])
```